# Dropdown box for each row (not in edit mode)

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is it possible to show a select box in view mode for each row. The select box contains different actions that can be performed. i.e.

Actions:
Go to page1
Go to page2
…

Row 1 can select page1, page2
Row 2 can select page1, page2, page3
…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter) to include `<select>` in the cells from the "actions" column. The custom formatter should return the HTML fragments as strings.

Later, inside of `loadComplete`, you can call something like `("#list select").bind('change', ...` to bind your "change" event handler which should be called if the user changes the item from the corresponding select. The exact code is depend on your implementation details: where you hold which information and how the actions "Go to page1" you want to implement.

Comment: I think it will work with custom formatter and then add the change event to the list. But I can see one drawback. If each row can choose different pages then I have to make a server request for each row.

Comment: @chitech: Sorry, but I don't see any problem. You can bind one function to all select elements which you included. Then inside of your `onChange` event handler you will have `event` as the first parameter. the `event.target` is the element which was changed. You can examine the selected item value with `$("option:selected",event.target).val()` and just set `windows.location` to the URL constructed based on the `$("option:selected",event.target).val()`. It should work.